# Multiple inputs for a python function

Tags: python

I am starting with Python, and trying to make a function.
The one i am in trouble is:

```
#~ this function should make a directory only if it doesn't exist
def make_dir(directoryname):
    if not os.path.exists(directoryname):
       return os.makedirs(directoryname)
    else: 
        print "la carpeta %s ya existe" %(directoryname)
```

What i want to know is if it is possible to give multiple inputs like

```
def make_dir(a,b,c,d,r)  #where a,b,c,d,r are directory names.
```

and how can i do it.

I apologize if it is an obvious question.

Comment: Use the `*args` syntax. This tells Python that a function can take a variable amount of arguments.

Comment: or pass them in a list then use a simple for loop

Comment: oh, oh. I wanted to avoid loops until i understand them better. I did not understand about `*args` but i will look in the web

Comment: See [Arbitrary Argument Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists).

Comment: @PM2Ring thank you

Comment: i just need to add `*` inside the function, am i right? @PM2Ring

Comment: To work with `*args` properly you _will_ need to understand loops, especially the `for` loop.

Comment: @PM2Ring thanks again. I will try to learn that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python has specific syntax for this. It is commonly referred to as `*args`. When Python sees this in a function definition, it allows the function caller to pass in a variable amount of arguments to the function.

The variable used in the `*args` syntax - which is a tuple - can then be used to access the arguments. In your case you can simply loop over the arguments and process them accordingly.

```
def make_dir(*dirs):
    for directory in dirs:
        if not os.path.exists(directory):
            return os.makedirs(directory)
        else:
            print "la carpeta %s ya existe" %(directory)
```

It is important to note you may name the *`args`* in `*args` anything you want. I renamed it `dirs`(short for directories). And while it is common practice to simply name it `*args`, in my opinion it is much better to rename it to fit each specific case. That way, you can clearly convey what kind of arguments your function expects.

Comment: And what if i just add `*` to the function in the original post? Would it be bad?

Comment: @santimirandarp Opps! I just realized my code wouldn't work. You'd need to use a manual for loop instead. See my edits.

Comment: This looks much better (to my unklowledge). I will try it.

Comment: I am not sure but, shouldn't it be "if not os.path"..etc?

Comment: @santimirandarp You correct. Thanks for catching the typo.

Answer (score 1):

Either pass your variables as a sequence such as a `tuple` or `list`. Or use the splat operator `*` to unpack a variable amount of arguments.

i.e.

```
def foo(*args):
    return args
```

**Sample Output:**

```
>>> foo(1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable arguments variable with *directorynames and use a for loop in the function:

```
import os

def make_dir(*directorynames):
    for dir_ in directorynames:
        if not os.path.exists(dir_):
            return os.makedirs(dir_)
        else: 
            print("la carpeta %s ya existe" %(dir_))
```

Regards.